# How to make python wait until the previous task is finished?

Tags: python, while-loop, speech-synthesis

Hi I am experimenting with Speech Synthesis on mac, and I always put while loops in my programs so that I can use them until I decide to stop, and with this code, it repeats "What would you like me to say?" At the same time it says whatever I tell it to say.

```
from Cocoa import NSSpeechSynthesizer
while 1==1
    sp = NSSpeechSynthesizer.alloc().initWithVoice_(None)
    sp.startSpeakingString_("What would you like me to say?")    
    say_1 = raw_input("What would you like me to say?")
    sp.startSpeakingString_(say_1)
```

Can someone tell me how to tell python to wait until it is done saying what I tell it to?

Comment: Well that depends, what does `sp.startSpeaking` does? It seems more of a responsibility of `NSSpeechSynthesizer` than Python itself. Doesn't that class have a method like `sp.waitUntilIsSaid`?

Comment: I can't test it, so I won't make it an answer, but take a look at instance method `isSpeaking` from the API (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSpeechSynthesizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_12) It seems like you could loop until _it is not speaking_. That way you can wait for it to finish.

Comment: @PauloBu This documentation is very unclear for use with python. Do you have any idea of how I could use it?

Comment: Can you post the link to the API's doc you are using?

Comment: @PauloBu [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSpeechSynthesizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_12) The same one you posted, I really understand better with examples, but I don't think this documentation is meant for use with python.

Comment: Try with this: `sp.startSpeakingString_(say_1);while sp.isSpeaking(): continue;print 'done speaking'`

Comment: @PauloBu Yep that worked like a charm! Thanks! Would you mind putting that in the answer so that others can see/ I can accept it?

Comment: I made an important edit to the answer (`time.sleep` versus `continue`) inside the loop. It is better that way.

Comment: @PauloBu Ok yeah I just read that and looked at my battery and was like woah, so thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are looking for [`NSSpeechSynthesizer` instance method: `isSpeaking`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSpeechSynthesizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_12). You can write a *polling loop* to test if it is speaking and continue to work once it is not anymore. Something like this:

```
import time
from Cocoa import NSSpeechSynthesizer
while 1:
    sp = NSSpeechSynthesizer.alloc().initWithVoice_(None)
    sp.startSpeakingString_("What would you like me to say?")    
    say_1 = raw_input("What would you like me to say?")
    sp.startSpeakingString_(say_1)
    
    while sp.isSpeaking():    # loop until it finish to speak
        time.sleep(0.9)       # be nice with the CPU
    
    print 'done speaking'
```

**UPDATE:** Is better `time.sleep` than `continue` inside the loop. The latter will waste a lot of CPU and battery (as pointed out by @kindall).

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is going to use 100% of a CPU waiting for the speech to stop. Among other things this will waste the battery of a portable user. You want to throw a `time.sleep(0.1)` or something in the body of the loop in place of `continue`.

Comment: @kindall I was just going now exactly to edit about that and suggest the `sleep`. I was first looking to at the API if there was something like a `callback`. Thank you very much for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the speech API does the speaking asynchronously. I don't know anything about this particular API, but to get this code working you'd have to poll in a loop or find an argument that specifies that your call should block. This issue is specifically connected to way this API works.

For this task, assuming you're using a Mac, you could use the command line instead. This will wait for the speech to finish before continuing.

```
import subprocess

def say(text):
    subprocess.call(["say", text])

print("Before")
say("Wait for me!")
print("After")
```